# Why can't load js file in my local apache2 server?

Tags: javascript

In my local domain's webpage , both
`jq.src = "https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.js";`
`jq.src = http://127.0.0.1/js/jquery-3.3.1.min.js`
can be loaded.

In the stackoverflow's webpage,right click to enter into chrome's inspect--console.

```
const jq = document.createElement('script');
jq.src = "https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.js";
document.head.appendChild(jq);
jq.addEventListener('load', () => {
  console.log("hello world");
  console.log($ === jQuery);
});
```

The remote jquery.js file can be loaded,now to replace it with local js file--`http://127.0.0.1/js/jquery-3.3.1.min.js` .
Why can't load the js file in my local apache2?

[image]

Comment: This path seems to be wrong

Comment: If your page is on https, your browser may prevent inclusion of http (unsafe) resources.

Comment: You may also want to check what port your local server is running on. Http defaults to port 80, so if your server is running on a port other than this you need to specify manually: `http://127.0.0.1:3000/js/jquery-3.3.1.min.js` for port 3000 for example.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sites you are visiting can apply security policy for javascript - which includes the debugger.  I think what you are seeing is the application of the content security policy associated with the web page you are visiting.

You can see this in the page headers.  In Chrome (as [explained here](https://www.mkyong.com/computer-tips/how-to-view-http-headers-in-google-chrome/)), you can view the html headers sent with the page:

Open the developer panel, select the "network" tab, and **reload the page**.

For stackoverflow, look under the "name" column for "stackoverflow.com" - there may be two if you originally loaded it via http, so find the one which is https - probably the second one.  Click that one, and select the "headers" tab on the right.  You will see in amongst the response headers:

```
content-security-policy: upgrade-insecure-requests
```

This is explained [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Content-Security-Policy/upgrade-insecure-requests).

Basically, it tells the browser that all http requests should be "upgraded" to https.  So when you try to access `http://127.0.0.1/...`, your browser upgrades the request to `https://127.0.0.1/...`, which your local server probably isn't set up to handle.

This is not limited to Chrome - all modern browsers [should do this](https://caniuse.com/#search=content%20security).

I browsed, for example, a few sites with Safari, and, in some cases, got an error message, such as on [GitHub](https://github.com/google/closure-compiler/wiki/A-word-about-the-type-Object):

```
Refused to load https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.js because
it does not appear in the script-src directive of the Content Security Policy.
```

That is another variety of content security policies you can read about [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Content-Security-Policy).

Answer (score 0):

try 
`jq.setAttribute('src',"https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.js");
jq.setAttribute('crossOrigin',"Anonymos")
jq.onload=onFinish;`

Comment: It would be useful if you also explained why your code snippet would work, and how (in your answer)

Comment: well, try using correct way to operate DOM element with set/get Attribute, and applying crossOrigin to get request may help to go through security issues

Comment: Please add such explanation to your code, not to the comment section